# Convert list details to array c#

Tags: c#, arrays, list

I'm trying to convert my list to a string array. My list is contains the following:

```
public class AcctList
{
    public string sRole { get; set; }
    public bool bIsPrimary { get; set; }
    public int iDayNo { get; set; }
    public bool bIsAirportMeetGreet { get; set; }
    public bool bIsSeaportMeetGreet { get; set; }
}
```

I then try to convert the list to a string array by doing the following:

```
 List<AcctList> userAccount = AccountBLL.GetUserInfoListByName(sUser);

String[] array = userAccount.ToArray();
```

However I cannot convert the list to an array. What can I do so that my list can be converted to an array?

Comment: It's obvious that you can't convert a list of *`AcctList`* to array of *`string`*. The same way you can't convert a single *`AcctList`* to a single *`string`*. You have to say how that kind of conversion should be performed first. Do you want to serialize `AcctList` instance into XML/JSON? Do you want just one property out of that object? Something else? Compiler will not make guesses here. Neither will I.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the modified class, you have to override your "ToString" method.

```
public class AcctList
{
    public string sRole { get; set; }
    public bool bIsPrimary { get; set; }
    public int iDayNo { get; set; }
    public bool bIsAirportMeetGreet { get; set; }
    public bool bIsSeaportMeetGreet { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return base.ToString();
        //return your desired string here
    }
}
```

Then using Linq select the ToString of each object.

```
string[] strings = userAccount.Select(p => p.ToString()).ToArray();
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

That's because calling the `ToArray()` method will create an array of the type of the list, in this case, a `AcctList[]`. If you want to convert it to a string representation, you need to say HOW. One example could be using LINQ with the `Select()` method, like `userAccount.Select(x => x.ToString()).ToArray()` or `userAccount.Select(x => x.sRole).ToArray()`.

Now, if you want to show information more than `sRole` you could use the first method and make your class override the `ToString()` method. Alternatively, you could format directly in the lambda expression. For example, `userAccount.Select(x => String.Format("Role={0},IsPrimary={1}", x.sRole, x.bIsPrimary)`.

Comment: `x => x.ToString()` will give you an array of `"Whatever.The.Namespace.Is.AcctList"`.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek yes, I know, but is a valid conversion. If OP wants to add information other than the `sRole`, overriding `ToString()` and using it in the select would be the way to go. Editted the answer to provide more information on this matter (formatting).